# Seting a Default Authorization Policy on multiple policies scenario

Tags: authentication, .net-core, authorization, policy

I'm setting 2 possible Policies for my application

```
services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
            {
                auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());

                auth.AddPolicy("apiKey", policy =>
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new ApiKeyRequirement()));
            });
```

It makes mandatory to use [Authorize(Policy="Bearer")] or [Authorize(Policy="ApiKey")] when calling my controllers.

Is there any way to set one of them as the Default, then, when I want to use it, I'm able to use just [Authorize] and  if I want to use the other one, I specify it?

E.g:

Setting the "Bearer" as default, then, when using a Bearer  scheme I just need to set [Authorize], but if I want to use the "ApiKey", I specify it by using [Authorize(Policy="ApiKey")]

Couldn't find any example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `DefaultPolicy` property lets you set the Default:

```
services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
            {
                auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());

                auth.AddPolicy("apiKey", policy =>
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new ApiKeyRequirement()));

                auth.DefaultPolicy = auth.GetPolicy("Bearer");
            });
```

in this case, when I want to use the "Bearer" scheme, I just need to use `[Authorization]`